# About export image sequence /video function for localhost or HDVG Engine in ORAD (3Designer) for C#?

Tags: image, c#-4.0, export, sequences

I am using Orad software for Graphic Render Real-time.
I use 3Designer for create template and HDVG for render tempate which includes my graphics.
I want ask: Do you know any tools or source code in C# for export scene into images sequence or movice (.avi file)?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by create a external program by C# which helped by a experts of ORAD,
Thank for reading.

Comment: Share the solution, then?